# ccavenue payment gateway integration in node js for restful api

Tags: node.js, ccavenue

I am a total new to payment gateways integration  . I would like to integrate CCAvenue to  using NodeJS  restful api. I have installed the CCAvenue package from npm, but  don't   [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ccavenue)    run

& i am also used  body-parser  in middleware

Comment: please give us more information. The problem might be you didn't save the module (`npm i --save ccavenue`) or from your body-parser that have these middlewares:
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

Comment: that bodyparser already using